# How to use a Service Reference with a basic authentication WCF SOAP Service

Tags: wcf, web-services, basichttpbinding, basic-authentication

I have a WCF SOAP service that uses basic access authentication.  SSL is not being used - I understand the security issues here.

Using the WCFTestClient application I have verified the service works by temporarily hard coding into the service a user name and password to use when the `Authorization` header is not present.

I am now trying to write a test application that passes the credentials via the `Authorization` header.  I've added a service reference to my service in my test app but the `Authorization` header is not present in the http request.  The generated `MyServiceClient` class uses `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`

In my test app I am setting the credentials as follows

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_MyService");
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "WebServiceUsername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "WebServicepassword";
```

I have also tried as follows

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "WebServiceUsername";
loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "WebServicepassword";
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>()); 
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials);
```

The service web.config is as follows

```
<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" >
    <endpoint contract="MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The test app.config is as follows

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:55314/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyService"
        contract="MyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: can you show sample xml that needs to be sent?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help as I'm using basic authentication.  WCF is handing all the serialization to and from XML, I never generate it.  I can try and get a dump from WireShark if you think ti could help.

Comment: Is is your service or you trying to send SOAP to someone's else service?

Comment: It is my service.  I have both JSON and SOAP endpoints.  Since I can add a SOAP endpoint as a service reference to my test app I was hoping to use that

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: My service is returning the status code HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized which web browsers correctly handle and prompt for credentials.  Inside my client a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException is being thrown with the text "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Comment: You need to see how your XML looks like and if the actual authorization header is being created. I've been working on similar problem recently and it took me a while to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good starting point, move your binding and endpoint info from config file to your class:

```
        protected BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            Name = "Name your binding here",
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
            AllowCookies = false,
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
            MaxBufferSize = 65536,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536,
            MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
            UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
            Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
            {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
            Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity() { AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default, ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName}, 
            Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity() { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest }
            },
        };
        protected EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:55314/MyService.svc");
```

and then

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endpont);
```

Try this, and tweak the binding into your needs, especially "Security".

Comment: Moving the config should not change anything. How does this actually send the credentials?

Comment: Worked for me for https service with basic web auth. Minor tweaking includes: `new HttpTransportSecurity {ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic}`

Answer (score 2):

BasicHttpBinding doesn't seem to have a Security Property in WP8, I am very frustrated with trying to access a sharepoint list under WP8.  Xamarin IOS/Android it is no problem.